# retrieve text from different rows from same column by searching in database table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to search in a database table for a particular word and want to retrieve a text from other column in the same row and there may be more than one rows where that word may exist, so i want all those rows where that word is.
i am using this code

```
$found = 'world';
$sql = "SELECT file_id FROM hello WHERE $field = '$found'";
$result = mysql_query( $sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
while($row)
{
    echo $row['file_id'];         
}
```

so my problem here is in database table i have only 5 rows and there are only 2 possible file_id to be printed after the code, but this while loop goes to infinite.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to put the `mysql_fetch_array` into the while loop: `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

Comment: have you tried changing your SQL to `SELECT file_id FROM hello WHERE $field LIKE '%$found%'` ?

Comment: $row aways true because is not empty

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix is this:

```
$found = 'world';
$sql = "SELECT file_id FROM hello WHERE field = '$found'";
$result = mysql_query( $sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['file_id'];         
}
```

But there are quire a lot other things to be corrected:

- use the mysqli extension, the mysql extension is deprecated
- you should use prepared statements to prevent sql injections
- you must add error checking and handling
- ...

Comment: i have done error checking and all.
its just that i know where the problem is, so i just put that part here.
thanks anyways

Comment: Take a look at the xdebug extension and configure your IDE to use it. It helps debugging such issues a lot because you see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

if you are starting a project use PDO

```
$db new PDO('mysql:host=localhost dbname=foo', 'user', 'password');

$sql = 'SELECT file_id FROM hello WHERE field = ? ';

$stmt = $db-prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $word);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $item){
   echo $item['key'];
}
```